# Extjs zend framework registration

Tags: javascript

1. create a registration form on the extjs

   ```
   var loginWindow;
   Ext.onReady(function() {

   loginWindow = new Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{
   title: 'Login',
   closable: false,
   draggable: false,
   resizable: false,
   width: 370,
   modal: true,
   items: [
       Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
           id: 'LoginForm',
           bodyPadding: 5,
           width: 350, 
           layout: 'anchor',
           defaults: {
               anchor: '100%'
           },
           defaultType: 'textfield',
           items: [{
               fieldLabel: 'Username',
               name: 'user',
               allowBlank: false
           },{
               fieldLabel: 'Password',
               inputType: 'password',
               name: 'pw',
               allowBlank: false
           }],

           url: 'album/saveform', // first one should be your controller, second one    the controller action (this one need to accept post)
           buttons: [
               {
                   text: 'Reset',
                   handler: function() {
                       this.up('form').getForm().reset();
                   }
               },
               {
                   text: 'Submit',
                   formBind: true,
                   disabled: true,
                   handler: function() {
                       var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                       if (form.isValid()) {
                           form.submit({
                               success: function(form, action) {
                                  Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Authenticated!');
                               },
                               failure: function(form, action) {
                                   Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', 'Authentication Failed');
                               }
                           });
                       }
                   }
               }
           ]
       })
   ]
   }).show();
   });
   ```
2. send data to the server to check

   ```
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
           $login =$_POST['user'];
           $pass =$_POST['pw'];

           if($login == '1' and $pass == '1' ){
               echo '{ "success": true}';
               //echo json_encode(array('success' => true));
               file_put_contents('7.txt', $login.$pass); 
           } else {
               echo '{ success: false}';
               file_put_contents('8.txt', $login.$pass); 
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Dunn come as records them in a file for testing
4. But I can not get an answer in the form of "success:true" help me send it to the form. As constantly get on failure!

Answer (score 0):

need to disable view in your Action!!!

in zf2

return $this->getResponse();

in zf

$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();